# PDF-Shuffler won't run

Tags: pdf, fedora

I am trying to use PDF-Shuffler on Fedora. When I try to launch the application from the start menu, nothing happens. When I run `pdfshuffler` from the command line, I get the message

```
Error: Could not import pdfshuffler
Cause: No module named pyPdf
```

I installed pyPDF, but when I do `import pyPdf`, I get the message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/usernumber/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyPdf/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf'
```

I didn't find a module named 'pdf' doing `pip search pdf`, so I don't know what module I am missing.

How can I get PDF-Shuffler to work?

Comment: The pyPdf module has not been changed for 10 years. I doubt that it is Python3 compatible. BTW: It does not require the module "pdf" but instead it tries to load the Python file "pdf.py" but it seems like Python misinterprets that. Try Python2 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments by @Robert, installing `pyPdf` for Python2 did the trick

```
pip2 install pyPdf
pdfshuffler
```

Comment: `pdfshuffler` will be replaced by [`pdfarranger`](https://github.com/jeromerobert/pdfarranger) (a fork), which is more actively developed. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1648514 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=762083

Answer (score 0):

pdfarranger is inferior to pdf-shuffler in that it cannot arrange pages automatically to print  1 - 4 on one side and 2 - 3 on the other (etc.) up to 200 hundred pages or so, for paper folding and binding into a book.  Shuffler does the job instantly with one keypress ... on windows. But i cannot get it to launch on Mint.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1153263)